# errors.Is returning false if it contains a slice

Tags: go

When I have an error struct that contains a slice nested within it errors.Is does not seem to work correctly:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type Response struct {
    Details []string
}

type ErrResponseError struct {
    Response Response
}

func (err ErrResponseError) Error() string {
    return "response error"
}

func main() {
    err := ErrResponseError{}
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "equal: %v", errors.Is(err, ErrResponseError{}))
}
```

returns

> equal: false

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type Response struct {
    Details string // Changed this line
}

type ErrResponseError struct {
    Response Response
}

func (err ErrResponseError) Error() string {
    return "response error"
}

func main() {
    err := ErrResponseError{}
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "equal: %v", errors.Is(err, ErrResponseError{}))
}
```

returns

> equal: true

................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> An error is considered to match a target if it is equal to that target or if it implements a method Is(error) bool such that Is(target) returns true.

So you can do this by writing an `Is` method that will compare the two slices.

The default error comparison algorithm checks if the error is equal to the target. Since your error contains a slice, it is not comparable.

Comment: Thanks! Would you say something like this would be idiomatic?

func (err ErrResponseError) Is(target error) bool {
 _, ok := target.(ErrResponseError)
 return ok
}

Comment: It would work. Idiomaticity is somewhat subjective here, I'd say not. Others may disagree.